# Spring AutoConfiguration manul import all components

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration

I have the following autoconfigure class.

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnWebApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties({LoggerProviderProperties.class})
@Import({LoggerController.class, LogService.class, LogConfig.class})
public class ProviderAutoConfiguration {

}
```

I need to import all the components, services, configurations using @import annotation, otherwise for example, when I remove LogService.class (LogController autowires LogService) from @Import parameters, it throws the following error

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.log.LogService' in your configuration.

Do I really have to include all of them manuelly as shown above, or is there any other way to automatically detect classes annotated Service, Component or Configuration?

**!This is starter library, not a executable app!**

Comment: Ideally you want `@Bean` methods for those classes in your `SimpleAuthenticationProviderAutoConfiguration` and add some `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` (for instance) so that users of your library can override them. Ofcourse you could use a component-scan but that might interfere with other component-scans and loading orders. So the best practice (check the spring boot and cloud auto configs) is to use `@Bean` methods.

Comment: M.Deinum you mean instead of putting for example LogService.class in Import annotation, I need to create a method annotated @Bean and it returns LogService eventhough LogService is annotated with Service annotation.

Comment: You then should remove the `@Service` annotation. Remember this is a library and you want to prevent users from accidentally scanning that package to suddenly detect those classes.

Comment: What about repositories and models? I added EnableJpaRepositories and EntityScan annotations to scan them.

Comment: You stated it is a library, however it looks like you have an app disguised as a library. Those 2 annotations will interfere with the users config (or the user that relies on auto-configuration which will be, partially, disabled). So you might want to choose wisely what you add were, without impacting users application (which currently it does).

Comment: Client will only add my lib as dependency and write some config in application.properties and nothing more. Basically it will be an app disguised as a library indeed. How can I use repository in a lib other than enabling jpa repos and annotating them @Repository.

Comment: That is your idea, however if you add `@EnableJpaRepositories` and `@EntityScan` it will impact the users application. It might disable things (which is what you don't want). So you also want to conditionally enable JPA repositories (and please don't add the `@Repository` annotation to the interface it adds nothing). What you should do is use `@AutoConfigurationPackage` to add packages instead of entity scan and componentscan (as that is side effect free). That with a conditional enabling JPA repositories should solve your issue(s).

Comment: @M.Deinum thank you so much for all the replies. I can accept it if you extract them into an answer.

Comment: HI, the answer was already there :). https://stackoverflow.com/a/69263827/2696260

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your "library" is that it already needs a lot of moving parts, like Spring Data JPA, properly setup JPA. If that isn't available it will fail, or if you add `@EnableJpaRepositories` and/or things like `@ComponentScan` and `@EntityScan` it will (quite severely) interfere with the (auto)configuration of Spring Boot or the clients. Which is what you want to prevent.

Instead of all those annotations what you need to do is

1. Conditionally enable `@EnableJpaRepositories` or just include the dependency and let the auto-configuration kick in (I suggest the latter)
2. Don't add `@ComponentScan`, `@EntityScan` etc. instead use [`@AutoConfigurationPackage`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/AutoConfigurationPackage.html) which is designed for starters.

```java
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnWebApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties({LoggerProviderProperties.class})
@AutoConfigurationPackage
public class ProviderAutoConfiguration {

}
```

**NOTE:** This assumes that the `ProviderAutoConfiguration` is in the same or a higher package then your other classes. If not specify the `basePackages` in the `@AutoConfigurationPackage`.

Comment: Did not want to directly ask but lookin for conditional jpa repositories for almost a day and could not find anything on it. In the first item, what do you mean by "include the dependency and let..."? which dependency?

Comment: Well what dependencies provided JPA repositories... Indeed Spring Data JPA.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *[@ComponentScan](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html)* to specify the packages you want to scan to find configurations and/or components to load.

Comment: It is a starter lib (forgot to include that in post). It is not a good practice to use ComponentScan in libs.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Spring Boot, at least so it seems according to your tags, you should take a look at `@SpringBootApplication`.

`@SpringBootApplication` encapsulates `@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration`, and `@ComponentScan` annotations with their default attributes. The default value for `@ComponentScan` means that all the sub packages on the package the `@ComponentScan` is used are scanned. That is why it is usually a good practice to include the main class in the base package of the project.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to write that it is a library (starter). So I cannot do that.

Answer (score 0):

If your components, services, configurations are under **com.log** as direct class or in sub-package, you can use **@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.log.*")**

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnWebApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties({LoggerProviderProperties.class})
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.log.*")
public class ProviderAutoConfiguration {

}
```